# saving image in NSURL from imagePickerController method

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, save-image

I am using the method below to get an image. What is the 'info' format and how am I going to save it into NSURL? I want to save the NSURL of the image into my core data.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
           [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
           self.photo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [description of all the keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a) in the `info` dictionary (scroll down to the Constants section).

- If you want the URL of the image, use
  `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.
- If you want to save the image itself to your Core Data store, use
  `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` or
  `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`, which will give you a `UIImage`
  object of the picture picked by user.